# Get all doc data from Cloudant as opposed to id, key, value

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchdb, cloudant, couchdb-nano

Trying to query against my db to get all docs with all info. The [db.list](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-nano#nanodblistcallback) functionality gets the overview of the docs but does not return all the data for the docs. Currently have to get the high level data then loop through the rows and query each individual doc. There must be a better way...

Is there a way to get all docs with the full set of info for each doc?

getting:

```
{
  "id": "0014ee0d-7551-4639-85ef-778f74365d05",
  "key": "0014ee0d-7551-4639-85ef-778f74365d05",
  "value": {
    "rev": "59-4f01f89e12c488ba5b8aba4643982c45"
  }
}
```

want:

```
{
  "_id": "14fb92ad75b8694c05b98d89de6e9b2d",
  "_rev": "1-6067c00b37a18ad8bab6744d258e6439",
  "offeringId": "ae0146696d1d3a90fe400cc55a97a60e",
  "timestamp": 1464165870848,
  "srcUrl": "",
  "score": 9,
  ...
}
```

Comment: what is document structure in db. you can query directly to interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The repository you linked to for nano looks like an outdated mirror. The [official repository](https://github.com/dscape/nano) includes documentation for [db.list](https://github.com/dscape/nano#dblistparams-callback) which also includes a `params` object. I would double-check your version of nano, but I would guess you already have a more recent version.

You can simply add `{ include_docs: true }` as the first argument to `db.list` and alongside `id`, `key` and `value`, you'll get a `doc` property that has the entire document.